# Gatsby deploy with aws codepipeline failing with max call stack error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gatsby, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm using an older version of Gatsby [v2.20.12](https://v2.gatsbyjs.com/docs/) as a basic markdown powered blog.  I have an aws CodePipeline setup (pipeline type v1, source Github V2) to build and deploy the project to an S3 bucket.

My latest pipelines are failing with the following error:

```
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
Command did not exit successfully npm install -g gatsby exit status 1
```

I've attempted to increase the CodeBuild environment to 15GB (8vCPUs), but the same error persists.

I'm trying to determine if there is some other configuration I should be using, whether that's the CodePipeline versions/config, the CodeBuild config, or if this old version of Gatsby simply does not play nice with this particular CI/CD solution?

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14911 Also what node version is being used in your build pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that CodePipeline and CodeBuild had changed drastically since I last did anything with this project, and I had to add some further configuration to the environment.  Specifically I needed an image with node v18.  Thanks to Bhavesh Parvatkar for his comment, which forced me to dig deeper into the environment image config.